# Javascript not returning value

Tags: javascript, recursion, return-value

The following is an example of a very simple recursive function.  As written, the code logs all the values >= to n, but it does NOT return the string value in the code block of the if statement. Can someone explain this behavior?

Thanks in advance to whomever is kind enough to respond to this question.

NOTE: my original post omitted the if statement.  I have since updated it.

```
function recursiveFunction(n) {
        console.log(n)
        if(n <= 1) {
            return "done";
        } 
        else {
        recursiveFunction(--n);
        }
    }
recursiveFunction(5);
```

Comment: Where *is* the `if`?

Comment: Well, in case the `else` block runs, there is no `return` statement

Comment: As written, the code won't log anything else than a syntax error (Unexpected token else). You can't have an `else` without an `if`. Can you edit your code to make it valid ?

Comment: I apologize profusely.  Yes, the if statement is missing. It should follow the console.log(n) function and read:  if (n <= 1) { return "done"}.  I wish I could edit my original post, but I unable to find a way to do so.  I hope this doesn't discourage others from responding.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function recursiveFunction(n) {
        console.log(n)
        if(n==0){            //you need an if statement        
            return  "done"
        } else {            
            return recursiveFunction(--n)     // return the recursive function   
        }                                     // with --n else there's no return
                                              // except when evaulated at 0
       
    }
  console.log(recursiveFunction(5))
```

Comment: Note than the `else` is useless

Comment: How so? the else provides the recursion call

Comment: You can keep the recursion call without the else ;)

Comment: sure, either way

Answer (score 0):

```js
function recursiveFunction(n) {
        console.log(n)
        if(n==0){            //you need an if statement        
            return  "done"
        }         
         return   recursiveFunction(--n)     
       
    }
  console.log(recursiveFunction(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add if statement. I think it`ll work.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  I unintentionally left out the if statement in the original post and have since updated it -- sorry for the confusion. However, what I did not intend to omit was the return keyword following the else statement. I thought there could only be one return statement in a function, but since I am using recursion, a return statement following the else statement is necessary in order to return a new value to the function declaration. So the return statement inside the else block returns a value to the function itself, whereas the return statement in the if block returns a value to the outside function call. If a return statement is NOT used inside the else block, it will return a value to the outside function call of undefined.  I appreciate everyone's effort at helping me arrive at this conclusion.  Please let me know if this makes sense, or if I've perhaps drawn the wrong conclusion.  Cheers

```
function recursiveFunction(n) {
        console.log(n)
        if(n <= 1) {
            return "done";
        } 
        else {
            return recursiveFunction(--n); // added the return keyword
        }
    }
recursiveFunction(5);
```